# How to create a dynamic list/ toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, enumerate

Thanks for clicking on my Question, im quite new to \Latex and maybe there exits a easy and simple  solution but i don’t get it. So my Problem:
Im writing a CV with coverletter and attachments, but in my coverletter i want at the bottom a list of all attachments.
At first I thought of something like a table of contents, but i couldn‘t get it to work. It looks like this:

-attachements(dir)
|__cv.pdf (file) 
|__something.pdf (file) 
-leter (dir) 
|__coverletter.tex (file) 
-main.tex(file) 
-custom.cls(file) 
-info.lco(file)

My coverletter.Tex looks like this:

```
\begin{letter}{\mToRecipient}
    %
    \opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren}
    %
    Some random text
    %
    Mit freundlichen Grüßen
    %\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
    %
    
    %\hspace{1cm}
    \parbox{5cm}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{unterschrift.png}\hrule\par
    \strut \centering\footnotesize \mSignature}
    \vfill\dotfill
    %\encl{\mAnlagen}
    % **Now here is my problem, i don’t know how to automatically insert my attachements**
    %
\end{letter}
```

My main.Tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass{custom}

\begin{document}


\include{letter/coverletter}
\includepdf[pages=-]{cv}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CV}
%i want hier some command to add my attachments to my coverletter
\addsomeattachement{CV}
\includepdf[pages=-]{something}
\addsomeattachement{something}

\end{document}
```

In the end ich want something in my letter like 
[image]

I’m flexible, it can also have a bulletpoint befor each attachement.

I hope my explanation is understandable and there are some elegant solutions. Thanks 
Optional: it would be nice if the enumeration and wording/ the word attachments is customizable and pagenumbering is not needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where can we find the documentclass `custom`?

Comment: @Mensch I load the documentclass  `scrlttr2` in my file custom.cls, i didn’t think it’s necessary but i can add the contents in my questions, but there isn’t something special like own commands, just some packages and options.